# Working with the absence of <> enclosing URLs while using RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, linked-data, rdflib

I have been using RDFLib to parse data and insert it into triplestores. A common problem that I have encountered is the absence of angle brackets enclosing the URLs when parsed from a Linked Data repository.

To upload the data, I have had to then manually add `<` and `>` and use `URIRef` to recreate the URLs.

Is something wrong with my approach? Is there a way to parse the URLs along with the angle brackets?

Here is the code:

```
#Querying the triplestore to retrieve all results
dbpediaSparqlEndpoint = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql/'
sparql = SPARQLWrapper(dbpediaSparqlEndpoint)
dbpedia_query = 'PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> DESCRIBE :Benin'
dataGraph = Graph()

sparql.setQuery(dbpedia_query)
sparql.method = 'GET'
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
output = sparql.query().convert()
# print list(output['results']['bindings'])
print type(output['results']['bindings'])

#Iterating through the output and adding the data to dataGraph
#First value is that of the index of the list
for index, value in enumerate(output['results']['bindings']): 
    #The encoding is necessary to parse non-English characters
    test = value['s']['value'].encode('utf-8')
    subj_raw = '<' + test + '>'
    subj_refined = URIRef(subj_raw)
    pred_raw = '<' + value['p']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '>'
    pred_refined = URIRef(pred_raw)
    if 'http' in value['o']['value']:
        obj_raw = '<' + value['o']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '>'
        obj_refined = URIRef(obj_raw)
    else:
        obj_raw = '"' + value['o']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '"'
        obj_refined = URIRef(obj_raw)
    dataGraph.add((subj_refined,pred_refined,obj_refined))
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the problem is. I'm not very familiar with RDFLib but your code for processing the query result seems needlessly complicated to me. A general tip: angle brackets are not actually part of the URI, which is probably why you don't see them back when processing the query result. I'm not sure why you believe you need to manually tag them back on, but you're probably making things way too difficult for yourself here.

Comment: I would also suggest that the RDFLib documentation gives a lot of information (including examples), on how to execute queries and process the result. See, for example, http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html

Comment: I have gone through the resource you mention. If I am not mistaken, angle brackets are necessary to enclose URLs in RDF. 

I have tried uploading triples without angle brackets to Sesame using RDFLib. Doesn't work. Once the angle brackets are added using the code above, the INSERT works without any issues.

This is the primary reason I'm curious about the angle brackets. Without them, (at least two) triplestores (Sesame, Dydra) don't accept INSERT and don't display any error.

I will be happy to be proven wrong and learn a easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: @kurious angle brackets are not part of a URI reference, and they're not needed "in RDF" (but RDF abstract data model, so that doesn't really make sense anyways). Angle brackets are used to "quote" URIs in SPARQL queries, just like double or single quotaction marks are needed to quote strings. It sounds like you're creating a sparql update from some results you read from somewhere else.  If that's the case, you may find "insert where" queries helpful (if applicable to your use case) and prepared statements (which RDFlib may or may not support,  I don't know).

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use sparql update. Thank you for the demonstration

Answer (score 4):

I think that it might be better to just combine your query and your update directly, which I *think* you can do without too much trouble.  I don't think you'll be able to use **describe** anymore, since its results aren't specified, but I think you could do something like this:

```sql
insert {
  ?a ?b dbr:Berlin .
  dbr:Berlin ?c ?d
}
where {
  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    ?a ?b dbr:Berlin .
    dbr:Berlin ?c ?d .
  }
}
```

However, if you really need to construct some queries and inject values into them from another source, that's the place where you should use *prepared queries*. [RDFlib supports prepared queries](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html#prepared-queries), so that you can do things like (example from the documentation):

> The initBindings kwarg can be used to pass in a dict of initial
>   bindings:
>
> ```sql
> q = prepareQuery(
>         'SELECT ?s WHERE { ?person foaf:knows ?s .}',
>         initNs = { "foaf": FOAF })
>
> g = rdflib.Graph()
> g.load("foaf.rdf")
>
> tim = rdflib.URIRef("http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card#i")
>
> for row in g.query(q, initBindings={'person': tim}):
>         print row
> ```

You could do something similar and have your query be:

```sql
INSERT DATA { ?s ?p ?o }
```

and pass it an initBindings argument to fill in the ?s ?p ?o values.